# uninitialized constant PostsController::Post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

**/config/routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users

  root 'posts#hello'

  resources :users
  resources :posts

end
```

**/app/controllers/posts_controller.rb**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_user! , except: [:hello]

  def hello
  end

  def new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.create(inner)
    redirect_to post_path(@post.id)
  end

  def index
    @posts = Post.all.order('id desc')
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find_by(id: params[:id])
  end

private 

  def inner 
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :desc)
  end

end
```

When I click *posts_path* link, I get an error: **uninitialized constant PostsController::Post app/controllers/posts_controller.rb, line 17**

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all.order('id desc')
end
```

Whats wrong?

**UPD**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates :desc, presence: true
  validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 45 }
end
```

**UPD2**

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :desc

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Could I see your post model? Does it actually exist?

Comment: Please post your `Post model` if it really exists.

Comment: show the migration file please...

Comment: Where is the model class `Post` located and what is the file name?

Comment: Hey did you run `rake db:migrate` ?  Check `rake db:migrate:status`, if the required migration file status is `up` or `down` ?

Comment: @KirtiThorat Thx! model had a name Posts.rb

Comment: It should app/models/post.rb and not Posts.rb

Comment: I am curious to know, didn't you use `rails g` for these stuffs? If so how this mistake happened... :(

Comment: If you created your model with the query `rails g model Posts`,then the file-name will be `posts.rb` and your `classname` will be also `Posts` not `Post`.I'm curious to know how you created your model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per Rails convention model names should be singular. So, model `Post` would be located under folder `app/models` and named `post.rb` and NOT `Posts.rb`. You are getting the error because Rails would look for a file named `post.rb` by *convention* and if not found it throws the error.